# Excel activex check box to enable or disable printing

Tags: excel, vba

hie

am looking for a vba code for controlling printing of excel sheet using activex check box in excel.

The code should only print the excel sheet when the checkbox is checked
and disable printing when unchecked.

i have tried the event below but it still prints and the msgbox is not showing

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
MsgBox "CANNOT PRINT, check box 1 is unchecked", vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

any suggestions?

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Take a look at the [`BeforePrint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195836.aspx) worksheet event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually test if the checkbox is checked or not. Also, you need to place this code inside the [ThisWorkbook](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/code.htm) module in the VBE.

Change sheet and checkbox name as needed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

   If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = False Then
     Cancel = True
     MsgBox "CANNOT PRINT, check box 1 is unchecked", vbOKOnly, "Error"
   End If

End Sub
```